# Failed Reference to IID_ICorProfilerInfo

Tags: .net, c++, api, com, profiling

I am trying to build a custom .NET profiler using the Profiling API and I am having an issue with the references in the project.  I am not a C++ engineer, so please bear with me.

I have created a simple COM server in Visual Studio 2010 in an ATL Server project.  Everything builds fine, up until I add the code to query the interface that is being served:

```
HRESULT hr = pICorProfilerInfoUnk->QueryInterface( IID_ICorProfilerInfo,
                                               (void **)&m_pICorProfilerInfo );
```

In the head file, I am referencing the cor.h and the corprof.h header files, but I am missing something.

As a reference, I am using the code from this site [Sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/dotnetprofiler.aspx) as a reference.

Any assistance would be appreciated and I realize this is probably obscure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably missing the linkage to corguids.lib, which holds the actual definition of `IID_ICorProfilerInfo` (in corprof.h it's only declared as `extern`). In the sample you mention, see [Building the Source Code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/dotnetprofiler.aspx#h6).